# He thought that I'm fool. This pissed me off. Combine 2 sentences

Tags: sentence-combination

How can I combine 2 sentences into 1 sentence?

> He thought that I'm fool. That pissed me off.

Thanks

Comment: He thought (that) I was a fool, which  pissed me off.  He thought I  was a fool, and that pissed me off,  That he thought I was a fool pissed me off.

Comment: **Fool** is a noun that requires an article before it. You might use the adjective **foolish** without an article.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this [reference in section 6](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/clause-phrase-and-sentence/verb-patterns/relative-clauses) could help, what you're looking for is a relative clause using "which" to give more information.

The word **that** in the second sentence refers to the whole previous sentence, but to combine using relative clause, you have to use **which** and must also have a comma.

> He thought that I'm fool, which pissed me off.

Comment: I think you've overlooked the missing article before "fool" - you might want to expand your answer to explain a little why it is necessary there.

Comment: Please edit your answer and include an article before **fool**.

Comment: @SovereignSun Even though **fool** is normally used with an article, it's informally also an adjective, so grammatically speaking, I don't think that's necessary.

Comment: @Gerry I know it as a noun and a verb only.

Comment: @SovereignSun Please consult with official sources before making a position or fixing someone.

Comment: @Gerry **fool** can be used as an adjective but only before a noun and means - *(informal) showing a lack of intelligence or good judgement*. Examples: **That was a damn fool thing to do!** and **That fool husband of mine locked us out of the house.** In your sentence it is a noun and not an adjective so it requires an article before it!

Answer (score 1):

You can combine you two sentences with a simple conjunction

> He thought that I'm **a** fool.
>   That pissed me off.

as

> He thought that I'm **a** fool **and** that pissed me off.
>   He thought that I'm **a** fool **which** *(really)* pissed me off.

Comment: Thank you for comments. Actually my first impression was something like "His thought about me being a fool pissed me off" . Is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, it can be understood that way also.